# Python Win32gui, Drawing on screen

Tags: python, winapi

I'm trying to draw a rectangle corresponding to the perimeter of a window, but I have trouble to find documentation about the functions contained in win32gui.

My question is, how can I draw That rectangle around the window? 
I've drawn directly on screen DC or creating a bitmap (win32gui.CreateCompatibleBitmap) and that paint I to screen DC?

```
Rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(window_handler)

dcBmp = win32gui.CreateCompatibleDC(0)
dcscrn = win32gui.GetDC(0)
c_bpm = win32gui.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcscrn, x, y)
c_bpm_old = win32gui.SelectObject(dcBmp, c_bpm)
pen = win32gui.CreatePen(win32con.PS_GEOMETRIC, win32api.RGB(255,0,0))
```

At this point I don't know how I can draw the Rect in bitmpap and then Paint it on Screen?

Thank you, I'm quite confused.

Sorry for my awful English, I hope you can understand my question, thanks again for your patience.

Comment: You cannot draw directly on the screen in any reliable way. The system will paint over what you draw.

Comment: This is a Win32 question, not essentially a Python question.  You should change the tags...

Comment: @ArminRigo I wish you hadn't done that, because I needed this information searching for "python win32gui drawrect", due to the missing tag - this came up WAY at the end of all search results. Added it back.

Comment: This might be useful to whomever ends up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62341134/how-to-draw-an-empty-rectangle-on-screen-with-python