# How to draw an empty rectangle on screen with Python

Tags: python, drawing, pywin32, updating, win32gui

I am not an expert and I am trying to show a rectangle on screen which follows mouse movements from a settle starting point, just as when you select something in word or paint. I came with this code:

```
import win32gui
m=win32gui.GetCursorPos()
while True:
    n=win32gui.GetCursorPos()
    for i in range(n[0]-m[0]):
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, m[0]+i, m[1], 0)
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, m[0]+i, n[1], 0)
    for i in range(n[1]-m[1]):
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, m[0], m[1]+i, 0)
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, n[0], m[1]+i, 0)
```

As you can see, the code will draw the rectangle, but the previous ones will remain until the screen updates.

The only solution I've came with is to take the pixel values i will paint before set them black, and redraw them every time, but this makes my code pretty slow. Is there an easy way to update the screen faster to prevent this?

...

Edited with solution.

As suggested by @Torxed, using win32gui.InvalidateRect solved the updating problem. However, I found that setting only the color of the points I need to be set is cheaper than asking for a rectangle. The first solution renders quite clean, while the second remains a little glitchy. At the end, the code that worked the best for me is:

```
import win32gui

m=win32gui.GetCursorPos()
dc = win32gui.GetDC(0)

while True:
    n=win32gui.GetCursorPos()
    win32gui.InvalidateRect(hwnd, (m[0], m[1], GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1)), True)
    back=[]
    for i in range((n[0]-m[0])//4):
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, m[0]+4*i, m[1], 0)
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, m[0]+4*i, n[1], 0)
    for i in range((n[1]-m[1])//4):
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, m[0], m[1]+4*i, 0)
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, n[0], m[1]+4*i, 0)
```

The division and multiplication by four is necessary to avoid flickering, but is visually the same as using DrawFocusRect.

This will only work if you remain bellow and to the right from your initial position, but it is just what I needed. Not difficult to improve it to accept any secondary position.

Comment: Also, a friendly reminder that you should mark your questions as solved if they solve your issue. It keeps the site from being cluttered with "unsolved" questions and users ending up here in the future might also find answers quicker :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to refresh the old drawn area, you need to either call [win32gui.UpdateWindow](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__UpdateWindow_meth.html) or something similar to update your specific window, but since you're not technically drawing on a surface, but the entire monitor. You'll need to invalidate the entire region of your monitor in order to tell windows to re-draw anything on it *(or so I understand it)*.

And to overcome the slowness, instead of using for loops to create the boundary which will take X cycles to iterate over before completing the rectangle, you could use `win32ui.Rectangle` to draw it in one go:

```
import win32gui, win32ui
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

dc = win32gui.GetDC(0)
dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(dc)
hwnd = win32gui.WindowFromPoint((0,0))
monitor = (0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1))

while True:
    m = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
    dcObj.Rectangle((m[0], m[1], m[0]+30, m[1]+30))
    win32gui.InvalidateRect(hwnd, monitor, True) # Refresh the entire monitor
```

Further optimizations could be done here, like not update the entire monitor, only the parts where you've drawn on and so on. But this is the basic concept :)

And to create a rectangle without the infill, you could swap `Rectangle` for `DrawFocusRect` for instance. Or for more control, even use [win32gui.PatBlt](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__PatBlt_meth.html)

And apparently `setPixel` is the fastest, so here's my final example with color and speed, altho it's not perfect as the `RedrawWindow` doesn't **force** a redraw, it simply asks windows to do it, then it's up to windows to honor it or not. `InvalidateRect` is a bit nicer on performance as it asks the event handler to clear the rect when there's free time to do so. But I haven't found a way more agressive than `RedrawWindow`, even tho that is still quite gentle. An example to this is, hide the desktop icons and the below code won't work.

```py
import win32gui, win32ui, win32api, win32con
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

dc = win32gui.GetDC(0)
dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(dc)
hwnd = win32gui.WindowFromPoint((0,0))
monitor = (0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1))

red = win32api.RGB(255, 0, 0) # Red

past_coordinates = monitor
while True:
    m = win32gui.GetCursorPos()

    rect = win32gui.CreateRoundRectRgn(*past_coordinates, 2 , 2)
    win32gui.RedrawWindow(hwnd, past_coordinates, rect, win32con.RDW_INVALIDATE)

    for x in range(10):
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, m[0]+x, m[1], red)
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, m[0]+x, m[1]+10, red)
        for y in range(10):
            win32gui.SetPixel(dc, m[0], m[1]+y, red)
            win32gui.SetPixel(dc, m[0]+10, m[1]+y, red)

    past_coordinates = (m[0]-20, m[1]-20, m[0]+20, m[1]+20)
```

---

Issues with positions and resolution? Be aware that high DPI systems tend to cause a bunch of issues. And I haven't found many ways around this other than going over to a OpenGL solution or using frameworks such as [wxPython](https://www.wxpython.org/) or OpenCV other than this post: [Marking Your Python Program as High DPI Aware Seamlessly Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401709/marking-your-python-program-as-high-dpi-aware-seamlessly-windows)

Or changing the Windows display scale to `100%`:

[image: 100%]

This causes the positioning issue to go away, perhaps take this to account by querying the OS for the scale and compensate.

---

The only reference I could find on the "clearing the old drawings" was this post: [win32 content changed but doesn't show update unless window is moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277773/win32-content-changed-but-doesnt-show-update-unless-window-is-moved) tagged `c++` win `winapi`. Hopefully this saves some people from searching before finding a good example.

Comment: @JoséChamorro I fixed the update problem by re-rendering the entire scene. It's a blit "glitchy" in terms of flickering, but that's because windows isn't hardware accelerated (that I know of) in the sense that the desktop should be rendered as fast as possible. So some optimizations has to be done to get a flawless experience.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer indeed solved my question. I would only add that, interestingly enough, I solved the 'glitchy' problem by adapting your suggestion of using win32gui.InvalidateRect  to the code I uploaded originally (check the correction above). It seems that it's cheaper to just set the color of a given set of points that asking for a defined rectangule, and the result is, I think, virtually the same as the one obtained by calling DrawFocusRect. I guess it is still a not very elegant solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoséChamorro Interestingly enough that works indeed. And I even tried `win32gui.LineTo` and they're horrifically slow. I'm going to continue playing around with this for a bit, but probably won't update here as it won't contribute to anything. But this is pretty interesting :) Good find!

Comment: @SaddamBinSyed You can read the comments or the answer, as there's some options in there. At the end, using `win32gui.SetPixel` to create the outline and `win32gui.InvalidateRect` to clear the old ones is the fastest.

Comment: @Torxed, I just found that DrawFocusRect is to draw the outline.  but I am getting the high flickering.  I am testing with your above code. pls advise to get rid of flickering

Comment: @Torxed in addition to above, I want to change the rectangle border color too.  please advise

Comment: @SaddamBinSyed Again, as pointed out. Flickering comes from windows not being designed for higher refreshrates. Instead, use `win32gui.InvalidateRect` to only clear the region you need in junction with `win32gui.SetPixel` in OP's post to set color and create the border.

Comment: @Torxed Thanks for the prompt response. I have tried to the color for the rectangle but no luck.   win32gui.SetPixel(dc, m[0], m[1], color) where color is green  = -16744448. please advise

Comment: @SaddamBinSyed I added my final example, after this you're on your own. This usage example is tricky at best. And it's going to get more complex the more you ask, If you have a specific issue I think it's best if you open your own question rather than hogging the comment section. See my edit for a `red` color rectangle that **tries** to refresh the window you're drawing on, ultimately, it's up to windows to honor that request to re-draw the window and how the window handles those events.

Comment: @Torxed, Thanks lot for your valuable response.

Comment: @SaddamBinSyed Did you post your question? I have the code you need including the solution for the color issue. I would love to answer my first question! (y)

Comment: @Torxed Hi, not to keep this going and going, but I just found that the updating part won't work at full screen... this is a nightmare! To be more clear and weird: I'm using this code to see the rectangle which will set the limits of a screenshot (with pyatogui) that is taken when clicking at the end point of the rectangle I want to define. So, when in full screen mode, I never get to see the rectangle... but all the intermediate rectangles I draw (but don't see!) while I drag the mouse will appear at the screenshot... Amazing! XD

Comment: @JoséChamorro It will, since it's technically a part of the actual screen rendering, essentially you're drawing your own window/icon on the sreen. So it's equivilant of creating a desktop application what we're doing here drawing pixels. This library is actually intended to do just that, create a window and draw in it, not draw on other "windows" (desktop is a window too). There are layers, for instance the cursor is on one layer/buffer and you could try finding out how to draw on a separate layer. Altho, probably tricky.

Comment: @Torxed I actually started by trying to draw over a different layer (not sure if I'm getting what you mean). I used pygame with a transparent screen... the problem there was that the goddam pygame won't get the cursor position when at transparent sections of the transparent screen... I just realized that... that can be solved simply by using win32 to get mouse position... I'll keep trying, thanks for your help and explanations!

Comment: @Torxed, I added a solution using pygame bellow. I would appreciate any comment on this method, as well as any optimization you may find. You may have had enough of this by now though xD (y).

Comment: @JoséChamorro, Thank you for your response. I didn't post a new question since I am facing the rendering(old rect are still showing in my screen) issue in my work station. do you have solution to that also?

Answer (score 2):

If you use OpenCV then it can be done like this

```
#draw either rectangles or circles by dragging the mouse like we do in Paint application

import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
mode = True # if True, draw rectangle. Press 'm' to toggle to curve
ix,iy = -1,-1

#mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy,drawing,mode

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix,iy = x,y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            if mode == True:
                cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
            else:
                cv2.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        if mode == True:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
        else:
            cv2.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)

#bind this mouse callback function to OpenCV window
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == ord('m'):
        mode = not mode
    elif k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is taken from the official opencv docs [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html#more-advanced-demo)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for a way to draw over the main screen, not over a new one

Answer (score 2):

After using @Torex solution for a while I got some problems, particularly, the rectangles I draw with that method doesn't show on full screen mode and they remain visible (paradoxically) if I get an screenshot of the section in which they were being draw, so the updating section of the solution doesn't work on full screen mode.

Bellow a maybe more complicated solution, with some pros and contras:

pros:

1. it enables to use pygame capabilities to easily add functions to the basic idea of drawing a rectangle, including easily changing its color, width, etc.
2. it works in any screen mode and.
3. it doesn't glitch while working

contras:

1. it does glitch at the beggining and in the end as pygame.display() is called and killed.
2. It requires to create an independent window.
3. You will need to adjust it to prevent clicking events take you out of the transparent window you're going to create.

The working code:

```
import win32api
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import win32con
import pygame
import win32gui
import pyautogui

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1)), pygame.FULLSCREEN, pygame.NOFRAME) # For borderless, use pygame.NOFRAME
done = False
fuchsia = (255, 0, 128)  # Transparency color
dark_red = (139, 0, 0)

# Set window transparency color
hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()["window"]
win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE,
                       win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE) | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED)
win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(*fuchsia), 0, win32con.LWA_COLORKEY)

#Some controls
block=0
block1=0

#You can render some text
white=(255,255,255)
blue=(0,0,255)
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32) 
texto=font.render('press "z" to define one corner and again to define the rectangle, it will take a screenshot', True, white, blue)
while not done:

    keys= pygame.key.get_pressed()
    pygame.time.delay(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    #This controls the actions at starting and end point
    if block1==0:
        if keys[pygame.K_z]:
            if block==0:
                block=1
                n=win32gui.GetCursorPos()
            else:
                done=True
                break
            #this prevents double checks, can be handle also by using events
            block1=10

        else:
            m=win32gui.GetCursorPos()
    else:
        block1-=1        

    screen.fill(fuchsia)  # Transparent background
    #this will render some text
    screen.blit(texto,(0,0))
    #This will draw your rectangle
    if block==1:
        pygame.draw.line(screen,dark_red,(n[0],n[1]),(m[0],n[1]),1)
        pygame.draw.line(screen,dark_red,(n[0],m[1]),(m[0],m[1]),1)
        pygame.draw.line(screen,dark_red,(n[0],n[1]),(n[0],m[1]),1)
        pygame.draw.line(screen,dark_red,(m[0],n[1]),(m[0],m[1]),1)
        #    Drawing the independent lines is still a little faster than drawing a rectangle
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,dark_red,(min(n[0],m[0]),min(n[1],m[1]),abs(m[0]-n[0]),abs(m[1]-n[1])),1)
    pygame.display.update()    

pygame.display.quit()
pyautogui.screenshot(region=(min(n[0],m[0]),min(n[1],m[1]),abs(m[0]-n[0]),abs(m[1]-n[1])))
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on this for a while based on some of the answers here and here is my solution.

This waits for the mouse to be pressed and dragged and creates a rectangle from pressed position to dragged position. On mouse release it will clear the rectangle and output the clicked and released positions and close all hooks.

There are a few issues I would like to solve (some slight flickering and the border being too thin) so if anyone knows anything about those I would appreciate some help (win32ui docs are really bad)

If you want a solid colour simply change `FrameRect((x,y,a,b),brush)` to `FillRect((x,y,a,b), brush)`

```py
from win32gui import GetDC, WindowFromPoint, SetPixel, InvalidateRect
from win32ui import CreateDCFromHandle, CreateBrush
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics, GetSysColor
from PyHook3 import HookManager
import ctypes
class Draw_Screen_Rect:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        dc = GetDC(0)
        self.dcObj = CreateDCFromHandle(dc)
        self.hwnd = WindowFromPoint((0,0))
        self.monitor = (0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1))
        self.clicked = False
        self.b1 = CreateBrush()
        self.b1.CreateSolidBrush(GetSysColor(255))
        self.final_rect = None
        self.refresh_frames = 0
        self.refresh_after = 10

    def _draw_rect_func(self):
        self.dcObj.FrameRect(tuple(self.pos), self.b1)
    def _refresh_rect(self):
        InvalidateRect(self.hwnd, self.monitor, True)
    

    def _OnMouseEvent(self, event):
        if event.Message == 513:
            self.clicked = True
            self.pos[0], self.pos[1] = event.Position
        elif event.Message == 514:
            self.clicked = False
            self.pos[2], self.pos[3] = event.Position
            self._draw_rect_func()
            self._refresh_rect()
            self.final_rect = self.pos
            self._destroy_hooks()
        elif event.Message == 512:
            if self.clicked:
                self.pos[2], self.pos[3] = event.Position
                if self.refresh_frames%2 ==0:
                    self._draw_rect_func()
                self.refresh_frames+=1
                if self.refresh_frames > self.refresh_after:
                    self.refresh_frames = 0
                    self._refresh_rect()
        return True
    def create_hooks(self):
        self.hm = HookManager()
        self.hm.MouseLeftDown = self._OnMouseEvent
        self.hm.MouseLeftUp = self._OnMouseEvent
        self.hm.MouseMove = self._OnMouseEvent
        self.hm.HookMouse()
        self.hm.HookKeyboard()

    def _destroy_hooks(self):
        self.hm.UnhookMouse()
        ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0)

    def output(self):
        return self.final_rect

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Draw_Screen_Rect()
    app.create_hooks()
    from pythoncom import PumpMessages
    PumpMessages()
    out = app.output()
    print(out)
```